# Finding index of a specific coordinate in an FEN string in python

Tags: python

In chess, FEN strings are used to describe chess board configurations. I have a function where I try to remove a piece from the string based on its chess board coordinates and then add it back according to its new coordinates.

I managed to make a loop to find the coordinates for the removal which works well, but the loop for the addition doesn't work.

`curFEN = "r5k1/5ppp/1p6/p1p5/7b/1PPrqPP1/1PQ4P/R4R1K"`

```
def ChangeFEN(Orig, New):

    global curFEN
    PrevX, PrevY = Orig
    NewX, NewY = New

    rows = curFEN.split("/")

    # delete piece from FEN string

    index = 0
    for i in range(PrevY-1):
        index += len(rows[i]) + 1

    space = 0
    index2 = 0
    #print(rows[PrevY-1])
    for index2, i in enumerate(rows[PrevY-1]):
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            space += int(i)
        else:
            if space == PrevX-1:
                break
            else:
                space += 1

    index3 = index + index2

    piece = curFEN[index3]

    if index3 == 0:
        a = "/"
    else:
        a = curFEN[index3 - 1]

    try:
        b = curFEN[index3 + 1]
    except IndexError:
        b = "/"

    if a == "/":
        if curFEN[index3 + 1].isdigit() == True:
            #print("letter, number")
            curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3] + str(1 + int(curFEN[index3 + 1])) + curFEN[index3 + 2 :]
        else:
            #print("letter, letter")
            curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3] + "1" + curFEN[index3 + 1 :]
    elif b == "/":
        if curFEN[index3 - 1].isdigit() == True:
            #print("number, letter")
            curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3 - 1] + str(int(curFEN[index3 - 1]) + 1) + curFEN[index3 + 1 :]
        else:
            #print("letter, letter")
            curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3] + "1" + curFEN[index3 + 1 :]
    else:
        if curFEN[index3 - 1].isdigit() == True:
            if curFEN[index3 + 1].isdigit() == True:
                #print("number, letter, number")
                curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3 - 1] + str(int(curFEN[index3 - 1]) + 1 + int(curFEN[index3 + 1])) + curFEN[index3 + 2 : ]
            else:
                #print("number, letter, letter")
                curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3 - 1] + str(int(curFEN[index3 - 1]) + 1) + curFEN[index3 + 1 :]
        else:
            if curFEN[index3 + 1].isdigit() == True:
                #print("letter, letter, number")
                curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3] + str(1 + int(curFEN[index3 + 1])) + curFEN[index3 + 2 :]
            else:
                #print("letter, letter, letter")
                curFEN = curFEN[0 : index3] + "1" + curFEN[index3 + 1 :]
    
    # add piece to FEN string

    index = 0
    for i in range(NewY-1):
        index += len(rows[i]) + 1
    #index = index - 1
    
    space = 0
    index2 = 0
    #print(rows[NewY-1])

    for index2, i in enumerate(rows[NewY-1]):
        if i.isdigit() == True:
            for j in range(int(i)):
                space += 1
                if space == NewX:
                    break
        else:
            if space == NewX:
                break
            else:
                space += 1

    #print(index)
    #print(index2)
    index3 = index + index2 #- NewY

    #print(curFEN[index3])
```

The code gets the index wrong whenever I move a piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It will save you a lot of hair loss to do it in grid co-ordinates

You could have functions to convert between grid and FEN formats in a manner that is easy to test.

Then it is very simple to start with a FEN, convert to grid, make the move, and then convert back to FEN if you must. For internal storage FEN is compact, but has no other real advantages.

(Do look up "bitboards" if you are desperate for compactness.)

One thing to watch out for in the code I have given below: for simplicity I am counting x and y between 0 and 7 inclusive (not 1 and 8). You can tweak it for 1-8 if you like.

```
def fenToGrid(fen):
    grid = []
    for fen_row in fen.split("/"):
        grid_row = ""
        for c in fen_row:
            grid_row += " " * int(c) if "1" <= c <= "8" else c
        grid.append(grid_row)
    return grid


def gridToFen(grid):
    fen_rows = [
        grid_row
        .replace("        ", "8")
        .replace("       ", "7")
        .replace("      ", "6")
        .replace("     ", "5")
        .replace("    ", "4")
        .replace("   ", "3")
        .replace("  ", "2")
        .replace(" ", "1")
        for grid_row in grid
    ]
    return "/".join(fen_rows)

def changeFen(fen, old_x_y, new_x_y):
    ox, oy = old_x_y
    nx, ny = new_x_y
    grid = fenToGrid(fen)
    grid[nx] = grid[nx][:ny] + grid[ox][oy] + grid[nx][1 + ny :]
    grid[ox] = grid[ox][:oy] + " " + grid[ox][1 + oy :]
    return gridToFen(grid)

# Testing that the functions work:
myFen = "r5k1/5ppp/1p6/p1p5/7b/1PPrqPP1/1PQ4P/R4R1K"
myGrid = fenToGrid(myFen)
backToFen = gridToFen(myGrid)
print(backToFen)
print(backToFen==myFen)

# Making a move
print(changeFen(myFen, (0, 0), (3, 3)))
```

Comment: ```grid[nx] = grid[nx][:ny] + grid[ox][oy] + grid[nx][1 + ny :]
    grid[ox] = grid[ox][:oy] + " " + grid[ox][1 + oy :]``` should actually be ```grid[ny] = grid[ny][:nx] + grid[oy][ox] + grid[ny][1 + nx :]
    grid[oy] = grid[oy][:ox] + " " + grid[oy][1 + ox :]``` as the grid is formatted as many rows instead of columns. Thank you for the answer though!

Comment: Ah yes! Sorry I missed that, but glad it worked for you.